# Page only loads the last linked javascript file, also google font API stopped working

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm programming a website in PHP 5 and for convenience I've elected to use includes for the header and footer on each page.

My html and head setup looks like this atm, and had been unchanged since I started

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <meta name='description' content=''>

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:regular,bold&subset=latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/default.css'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bbeditor.css'>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="js/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="js/bbeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    </head>
```

As you can see I use some jquery, a nice simple bbeditor for user input and the google font api. What started happening was that I could only load the last mentioned javascript file for some reason, in this case, it would be the bbeditor. not only that, the font api just wont load at all.

I should mention that the CSS files load perfectly fine however.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: You'll need to look at what HTML is being sent *to the client*. There's probably some problem expanding/applying the template.

Comment: I am really unfamiliar with that concept. are you saying its an htacess problem?

Comment: Do a "view source" or "show source" of your page in browser and paste here

Comment: There is no difference between the page source and what I see in dreamweaver.

Comment: Have you tried opening the page with Firebug? Which scripts are show in the scripts tab and does it report any errors?

Comment: I have discovered the issue, There was a conflict with a .xml file dreamweaver created to discover dynamically-related content called dwsync.xml, this file was in a folder called _notes inside my includes folder, the very folder holding my header.php and footer.php. removing the file from my server solved the problem.

Comment: the xml file only solved the font api issue, the javascript issue remains. i will look at firebug now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using firebug's "Net" tab, it will show you all the requests and responses. Firstly check the Status column and, if something's wrong, the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try closing your one-line tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <meta name='description' content='' />

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:regular,bold&subset=latin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/default.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/bbeditor.css' />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="js/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="js/bbeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    </head>
```

Note the `/>` at the end of `link` and `meta` tags.